# global variable is empty

Tags: coldfusion, global-variables, cfml, lucee

I'm using Lucee CFML to create a website.

I have a global variable stored in application.cfc like this:

```
component {
    application.globalquery;
}
```

On the second page of the website, I assign a value to that variable:

```
<cfscript>
    myquery = ["object1", "object2", "object3", "object4", "object5"];
    application.globalquery = myquery;
</cfscript>
```

On a third page, I dump the globalquery variable:

```
<cfscript>
    dump(var="#application.globalquery#");
</cfscript>
```

But the result of this dump is `string: empty`

The expected behavior should be, that it contains the 5 `objects` of `myquery`.

Why isn't that the case?

Comment: Dump your "myquery" variable before assignment to the application scope. Is it also empty? Dump your entire "application" scope. Is it completely empty?

Answer (score 3):

You're resetting the value on every request.

By putting the definition at the root of the component:

```
component {
    application.globalquery;
}
```

You're essentially telling CF to run that code on every request, like this:

```
component {
    function onRequestStart() {
        application.globalquery;
    }
}
```

You need to define that variable only once, when the application starts, like this:

```
component {
    function onApplicationStart() {
        application.globalquery;
    }
}
```

From then on, the value should only change when you tell it to change.

Here's more info on [Application.cfc](https://cfdocs.org/application-cfc). There may be a few differences between Adobe CF and Lucee.

Comment: I tried it with onApplicationStart, but the value stays saved in that global variable, even if I leave the page and return later. 

Like I have another global variable that is set to 1 in the "onApplicationStart()" method.
Everytime I click on a new page, I increment that number. After 3 pages, the stored value is 4.
Now I close the website (server's still running) and return to it and the value is still set to 4. When I go to another page of that website it increments to 5 and so on. 
Is it possible to only stay the same while the user is on that website?

Comment: The "Application" scope is global to the running application (i.e. same for all users of the application). The "Session" scope is global to the user (each user has their own set of variables). Sounds like you want to use the Session scope for these variables, not the Application scope. The session scope works in much the same way as the application scope with it's own specific methods in Application.cfc.